# call action method without page reload except ajax call in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

Can we call our controller action method without page reload except ajax call, If yes then how ,please describe it briefly.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no persistent connection between the client and the server you are not directly able to do that. I assume that you mean any kind of Http-Request with Ajax. Another idea is to use WebSockets to get a persistent connection between server and client. But that needs a Server-Implementation and is not as easy as just making one Http-Request. You have to care about Dependency Injection and Instance Creation of the Controller and I would recommend you to use http, except you have a really complex use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RenderAction for call the controller action with out using ajax call.

```
@{Html.RenderAction("your action name","your route parameters")}
```

Comment: I think this option forces a page refresh because in the Action, you have to return a new View. If that is the case, it doesn't do what the OP requested.